# Error con cliente strophejs

Tags: apache, xmpp, ejabberd

Ejabberd.yml version 18.03

Puerto:

```
port: 5280
ip: "::"
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/bosh": mod_bosh
  "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  "/api": mod_http_api
##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
web_admin: true
## register: true
## captcha: false
```

---

Modulo : (el modulo http-bind en esta version no se encuentra)

```
mod_bosh: {}
```

strophejs:

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://localhost/xmmp-httpbind';
```

---

apache httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>

  Order deny,allow

  Deny from all

  Allow from all

</Proxy>

ProxyPass /xmpp-httpbind http://localhost:5280/bosh/

ProxyPassReverse /xmpp-httpbind http://localhost:5280/bosh/
```

---

configuracion del archivo hosts:

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1   localhost
    ::1 localhost
```

---

Error por consola:

> Failed to load http://localhost/xmmp-httpbind: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:88' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadir http-bind: true y reiniciar el servidor y cambiar /bosh/ por /http-bind/ en el proxy y añadir el modulo mod_http_bind {} despues del mod_bosh

Comment: Hola! Tu respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad, considera añadir una explicación de como esto resuelve el problema del autor. Para mas información puedes leer [answer]